# The most convenient way to check if a string ends with some text in OCaml?

Tags: regex, string, ocaml

Hi I've been checking on the internet to find a good way to implement "whether a string ends with certain text" in OCaml and I found that to manipulate string in OCaml is not as trivial as I expected compared to other programming language like Java.

Here is my OCaml code using Str.regexp to check if the **file** name ends with "**.ml**" to see if it is an OCaml script file. It does not work as I expected though:

```
let r = Str.regexp "*\\.ml" in
if (Str.string_match r file 0)
  then
    let _ = print_endline ("Read file: "^full_path) in
    readFile full_path
  else
    print_endline (full_path^" is not an OCaml file")
```

Note that **readFile** is a function written by myself to read the **file** from constructed full_path. I always got results in the output such as

```
./utilities/dict.ml is not an OCaml file
./utilities/dict.mli is not an OCaml file
./utilities/error.ml is not an OCaml file
./utilities/error.mli is not an OCaml file
```

What is wrong with my regexp in OCaml and is there a better/simpler code for checking string?

Comment: You have a String.length function (even String.sub if you need it) and you can access the nth character of a string s using the syntax `s.[n]` (eg `"abcde".[1]` will evaluate to 'b'). I fail to see what's missing comparing to other languages ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Yann. But in OCaml I can only check the index of one char but not the whole string. Imagine if I want to look for a long string in a paragraph of text, I might have to check one char by one char of my long string... It's not very convenient.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand exactly what you mean. For the problem "whether a string s1 ends with certain text s2", you have to loop char by char anyway in any language. You can even do in OCaml : `let ends_with s1 s2 = let n1 = String.length s1 and n2 = String.length s2 in n1 >= n2 && String.sub s1 (n1-n2) n2 = s2`. But the standard library is quite minimal indeed : if you are interested in extended functions for String manipulation, you can take a look at Batteries library, especially the BatString modyke : http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatString.html

Comment: @YannHamdaoui Thanks for your reply. In Java, I can simply use my_string.indexOf("substring") to know the beginning position of substring in my_string then I can check if the position returned is -1. It's only two line of code (or I can use directly my_string.endsWith("substring") with only 1 line of code). In OCaml, String.contains only accepts one char but not the whole substring, which means I still have to manipulate the char-check looping by myself...

Comment: OCaml standard library is a thin layer on top of which other libraries can be built. Use core or batteries libraries, they have lots of stuff in them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all your regexp is incorrect, you forgot `.` before the `*`, the correct version is:

```
let r = Str.regexp {|.*\.ml|}
```

Note the usage of a new string literal syntax, that allows you to write regex in a nicer way without tons of backslashes. Using a regular syntax, with double quotes, it should look like this:

```
let r = Str.regexp ".*\\.ml"
```

This regular expression is not ideal, as it will match with `file.mlx`, `file.ml.something.else`, etc. So, a better version, that will match with all possible OCaml source file names, is

```
let r = Str.regexp {|.*\.ml[ily]?$|}
```

Instead of using regexp you can also use `Filename` module from the standard library, that has a `check_suffix` function:

```
let is_ml file = Filename.check_suffix file ".ml"
```

To check all possible extensions:

```
let srcs = [".ml"; ".mli"; ".mly"; ".mll"]
let is_ocaml file = List.exists (Filename.check_suffix file) srcs
```

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, I would expect the regexp to work better if anchored to the end of string, i.e. appending a `$` (assuming this is supported in OCaml).

Comment: @unwind : indeed, and it is supported (http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html)

Comment: @ivg Just one more question out of curiosity, why do you use {| ... |} instead of string quote " ... ". Is it an array?

Comment: It is not an array, it is a new syntax for string literals, array is `[| |]`. It allows you to use special characters without escaping, so that if you want literally \, you don't need to escape it with \\. This is especially good for regular expression, as `{|\(x\|y\)|}` is much better than `"\\(x\\|y\\)"`

Answer (score 3):

Probably, you are confused with two styles of regular expressions:

- Glob (like regexp in `bash` or other shells)
  You know, `*` matches empty string or a sequence of any characters in this style.
- Posix (same as this case)

You need to check the document of `str` carefully.
http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html

This says 

`. : Matches any character except newline
* : Matches the preceding expression zero, one or several times`

You see, `str` library adopts latter style.
So, to define `Str.regexp`, you need to write like

```
let r = Str.regexp ".*\.ml";;
val r : Str.regexp = <abstr>

Str.string_match r "fuga.ml" 0;;
- : bool = true

Str.string_match r "fugaml" 0;;
- : bool = false

Str.string_match r "piyo/null/fuga.ml" 0;;
- : bool = true
```

If you want to use glob style regular expressions,
you can use [re](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re).

In my opinion, you don't need to use a regexp to solve your problem.
Just judge whether the input includes substring ".ml" via appropriate functions.

Comment: Thanks @nomaddo ! The way to include whether the input includes substring ".ml" in Java is 

int pos = my_text.indexOf(".ml") 

then check if pos == -1. But this kind of function does not exist in OCaml...

Comment: > But this kind of function does not exist in OCaml...

That's not true, it exists. For example, in the Core library, there is a `String.is_suffix`  function that `returns [true] if [s] ends with [suffix]`. Specifically for your use case, there is a `Filename.check_suffix` that will even work crossplatform, and check suffixes caseless on Windows

Comment: @ivg I am a bit confused by the online document. In http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/String.html There is no is_suffix. Am I looking at the wrong page?

Comment: Because it is not in the standard, it is in the Janestreet Core library:
https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core/Std/String.mod/
It is very easy to start to use it, just do `opam install core`, play in the interactive `coretop` and compile with `corebuild`. Learn it with Real World OCaml book, https://realworldocaml.org/

Comment: It shall not be called CORE if it's not in the default package of OCaml, don't you think? It should called janestreet XD Understood now. Thanks man.